# Model shows google.protobuf.message.decodeerror: error parsing message

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, protocol-buffers

I am using facenet model.... When i am doing classifier training it shows this message, but image alignment process with this model is going good...

```
def load_model(model):
# Check if the model is a model directory (containing a metagraph and a checkpoint file)
#  or if it is a protobuf file with a frozen graph
model_exp = os.path.expanduser(model)
if (os.path.isfile(model_exp)):
    print('Model filename: %s' % model_exp)
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_exp,'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        print("Graph def value: ",graph_def)
        print(type(graph_def))
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```

Can anyone help me to clear this issue?
And also the above code works well in local the issue occurs in heroku server

In the above code the print statement shows an op as,

```
Graph def value:
<class 'tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2.GraphDef'>
```

Below is a screenshot for an issue:
[image: Below is a screenshot for an issue]

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the model serving support is not working on heroku... Better you need to use the paid account on heroku with machinelearning dependencies... Or you can go with some other online deployment which supports tensorflow model serve.